# F# - Error Loading Table With Empty Last Row Using HtmlProvider

Tags: f#-data

When loading a Wikipedia table using HtmlProvider, I get an error message because the last row in the table is empty!

```
module SOQN = 

    open System
    open FSharp.Data

    let [<Literal>] wikiUrl  = @"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COVID-19_testing#Virus_testing_statistics_by_country"
    type Covid = HtmlProvider<wikiUrl>

    let main() =
        printfn ""
        printfn "SOQN: Error Loading Table With Empty Last Row Using HtmlProvider?"
        printfn ""
        let feed = Covid.Load(wikiUrl)
        feed.Tables.``Virus testing statistics by country``.Rows
        |> Seq.map (fun r -> r.Date) 
        |> printf "%A "
        printfn ""
        0

    [<EntryPoint>]
    main() |> ignore
    printfn "Fini!"
    printfn ""

// Actual Output: 
// "Date is missing"
// 
// Expected Output: 
// seq [ "Albania"; "19 Apr"; "5542"; "562"; "10.1"; "1,936"; "196"; "[121]" ]
// ... 
//
```

What am I missing?

For instance, can I preset the column types to 'string' similar to using 'schema' with CsvProvider?

Comment: Maybe the page has changed? It works for me:  seq
  [Some 4/1/2021 12:00:00 AM; Some 4/1/2020 12:00:00 AM;
   Some 4/1/2019 12:00:00 AM; Some 4/1/2022 12:00:00 AM; ...] EDIT: date parsing does not look right, though

Comment: @TurboHz. Thanks for the sanity-check. Unfortunately, it still fails for me!

Comment: I tried rolling back FSharp.Data to previous versions, and I still get the results. See this jupyter [notebook](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/turbohz/stackoverflow-notebook/master?filepath=htmlprovider-covid-19.ipynb). The Date parser seems to be confusing the day with the year, though.

Comment: @TurboHz. Excellent idea using the Jupyter notebook. I downloaded it from Binder and ran it locally with the following error:

Comment: Unhandled Exception
Date is missing
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.PrintfModule.PrintFormatToStringThenFail@1637.Invoke(String message) in F:\workspace.1\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\printf.fs:line 1637
   at FSI_0009.main@11-4.Invoke(String[] row)
   at FSharp.Data.Runtime.BaseTypes.HtmlTable`1.Create(Func`2 rowConverter, HtmlDocument doc, String id, Boolean hasHeaders) in C:\GitHub\dsyme\FSharp.Data\src\Html\HtmlRuntime.fs:line 391
   at FSI_0009.main()
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0009>.$FSI_0009.main@()...

Comment: I don't think I can provide further assistance with this. The issue appears to be particular to your setup, so not a bug in the library, or malformed data.

Comment: @TurboHz. No problem. Thanks again for the benefit of your expertise.